# Creating a Multi-SIM Cellular Connectivity Solution for Raspberry Pi Zero 2 W

Tags: wireless-communication

I'm looking to set up my **Raspberry Pi Zero 2 W** so it can use **various SIM cards from different telecom providers.** While this might sound unusual, it's actually quite practical. In some areas, certain networks might be unavailable, but switching to a different provider's SIM card could solve the problem. My goal is to create an application that **automatically switches between these SIM cards until it finds a viable network connection** (they are three cards with three different telecom providers that I need).

What components I should purchase to achieve this setup? Additionally, I'm concerned about **minimizing the thickness or depth** of the setup. In my case, relying on the height of the components may be a better approach than stacking the cellular modem on top of the RPI (they are three cards with three different telecom providers that I need).

Comment: this question is not Raspberry Pi specific ... the SIM card is internal to the cellular modem, and is not connected the the RPi ... you will need three cellular modems, unless you can find one that can handle multiple SIM cards